# JMS MessageCreator.createMessage() in Grails

Tags: exception, grails, jms, message, sendmessage

I am trying to implement jms to my grails application.

I have several JMS consumer in a spring based enviroment listining 
on an ActiveMQ broker. I wrote a simple test commandline client which creates
messages and receives them in an request response manner.

Here is the snippet that sends a MapMessage in Spring JMS way.
This works for me as long I am in my spring world.

```
final String corrID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
asyncJmsTemplate.send("test.RequestQ", new MessageCreator() 
{
 public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
  try {
   MapMessage msg = session.createMapMessage();
   msg.setStringProperty("json", mapper.writeValueAsString(List<of some objects>));     
   msg.setJMSCorrelationID(corrID);
   msg.setJMSReplyTo(session.createQueue("test.ReplyQ"));
   return msg;
  } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;
 }
});
```

**BUT** when I tried to implement this methods to my grails test app
I receive some METHOD_DEF exceptions. Sending simple TextMessages 
via the jmsTemplate.convertAndSende(Queue, Message) provided by 
the JMS Plugin works.

Can any one help me? Is this a common problem?

Cheers Hans

Comment: BTW, just like with 100s of other questions about anything... it's almost always better to show the exception(s), even if it's just the first line, than to say "some XXX exception".

Answer (score 0):

Not actually trying this out, I have to believe this is a syntax problem.   What you're really doing with that anonymous class is passing a closure containing all the MessageCreator code into the constructor for the MessageCreator class.  In Groovy, closures can be passed as the last argument to a function merely by placing it after the function name or the parenthesized first arguments.

```
SomeFunction( arg1, arg2) { some code }
```

is the same as

```
SomeFunction( arg1, arg2, { some code } )
```

What you really want is to convert the closure into an anonymous instance of a MessageCreator, which I believe you can accomplish by:

```
asyncJmsTemplate.send("test.RequestQ", 
          { code in the anonymous block } as MessageCreator );
```

I found this on StackOverflow, actually, though it's a poorly created question.  Read all the responses, and you should see something relevant: [Best groovy closure idiom replacing java inner classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758700/best-groovy-closure-idiom-replacing-java-inner-classes)

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problems and here is my working solution:
I have created a new class MyMessageCreator in the src folder which implements the origin JMS MessageCreator interface.

With this I can create a new MyMessageCreator object and can call the createMessage(Session session) function to generate a new message.

To get the session object I use the jmsTemplate.

```
public class MyMessageCreator implements MessageCreator {

    @Override
    public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
        return session.createMapMessage();
    }

}
```

Here is the relevant groovy code:

```
Session session = jmsTemplate.getConnectionFactory().createConnection().createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
MapMessage msg = new MyMessageCreator().createMessage(session);
```

Hope this helps,
Mirko